# searching and filtering into list box and combo box

Tags: vba

With those code is be able to search all the value from the A column but did have any way to filter it? like base on B,C,D column is empty or got value.

Final result will be like if B or C or D column is empty then the A column Title will list in X ,if B,C,D is got value then the A column title will list in Y.

***So the A column will return to listbox or combobox base on column B,C,D is empty or not**

```
 With Worksheets("sheet1")

Me.x.List = .Range("A1:A" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
Me.y.List = .Range("A1:A" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value

 End With
```

attached is the result look like:

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4R48.jpg)

Comment: Instead of picking up the array from the range's `Value`, you'll need to construct an array by looping over the rows and checking for the appropriate matches

Comment: @TimWilliams you mean is check by the B,C,D column first then go to next row?

Comment: Yes - you will need to check each row for values in Cols B/C/D

Comment: @TimWilliams okay,but do you have a sample for me refer to? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**i solved by myself**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim X As Long
    Dim Y As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sht1")
    Y = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For x= 1 To Y 
        If ws.Range("B" & x) ="" or ws.Range("C" & x) = "" or ws.Range("D" & x) = ""Then
            Me.ListBox1.AddItem ws.Range("A" & x)
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```